# Get second part of output separated by two spaces

Tags: bash

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1

find "$path" -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | sort | uniq -D -w 32
```

It outputs this:

```
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16  ./dups/dup1-1.txt
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16  ./dups/dup1.txt
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826  ./dups/subdups/dup2-2.txt
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826  ./dups/subdups/dup2.txt
```

Now I only want to save the last part (the path) in an array.
When I add this after the sort

```
| awk -F "  " '{ print $1 }'
```

I get this as output:

```
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826
```

When I change the `$1` to `$2`, I get nothing, but I want to get the path of the file.

How should I do this?

EDIT:

This script

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1

find "$path" -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -D -w 32
```

Outputs this

```
parallels@mbp:~/bin$ duper ./dups
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826
ffc752244b634abb4ed68d280dc74ec3152c4826
```

When I change it to `$2` it outputs this

```
parallels@mbp:~/bin$ duper ./dups
parallels@mbp:~/bin$
```

**Expected Output**

```
./dups/dup1-1.txt
./dups/dup1.txt
./dups/subdups/dup2-2.txt 
./dups/subdups/dup2.txt
```

There are some files in the directory that are no duplicates of each other. Such as nodup1.txt and nodup2.txt. That's why it doesn't show up.

Comment: Remove the ```-F "  "``` argument and use ```$2```.

Comment: @accdias When I do that it still outputs nothing.

Comment: I just tested the exact same thing you did and here the output is, as expected, the filenames.

Comment: I tested your code with and without -F and works (linux + bash 4.3)

Comment: @accdias Can you take a look at the edit? This is the exact thing I'm trying

Comment: Now I see the same effect you described. It is caused by the ```uniq```. Remove it and test again. I don't know exactly what is wrong with it but it is the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @accdias Ah I see, but the whole thing is that I'm getting the duplicates. Now it shows me all the files unfortunately.

Comment: Now I see the problem. The filenames are NOT duplicates, so ```uniq -D``` doesn't show anyhting.

Comment: @accdias Ah I see, how can I still get the duplicates but only store the filenames in the array?

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Check this post: [How to delete duplicates of files in directory and subdirs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26477/how-to-delete-duplicates-of-files-in-directory-and-subdirs)

Comment: @accdias I know that fdupes exists. I just wanted to do this for my own training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `find` command to this:

```
find "$path" -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | uniq -D -w 41 | awk '{print $2}' | sort
```

I moved the `uniq` as the first filter and it is taking into consideration just the first 41 characters, aiming to match just the `sha1sum` hash.

Comment: Bear in mind that ```sort``` in the end of the command will mix the results and you will not be able to know which file is a duplicate of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result piping to `tr` and then `cut`:

```
 echo '3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16  ./dups/dup1-1.txt' |\
      tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Outputs:

```
./dups/dup1-1.txt
```

- `-s ' '` on **tr** is to *squeeze* spaces
- `-d ' ' -f 2` on `cut` is to output the second field delimited by spaces

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `cut` for stuff like this. With this input:

```
3c8b9f4b983afa9f644d26e2b34fa3e03a2bef16  ./dups/dup1-1.txt
```

I'd do `cut -d ' ' -f 2` which should return:

```
./dups/dup1-1.txt
```

I haven't tested it though for your case.

**EDIT**: Gonzalo Matheu's answer is better as he ensured to remove any extra spaces between your outputs before doing the cut.